# How can I make my Physics Particles more Realistic?

Tags: javascript, particle-system, particles

I have a simple particles system on CodePen.  The particles can bounce off each other, and can bounce off the mouse.  Right now, the the particles go into each other a little bit before popping out like normal physics.  How can I make this more realistic?

```
Here's the private pen -
http://codepen.io/alexsafayan/pen/5030eda1329586f457bd56c5d33da54f/
```

Comment: add friction meaninjg acceleration / deceleration

Comment: add some frictikon dceleration factor (also called easing in animation). so initialy a particle gets a boost and by hiting other particles it decelerates with some factor and / or by friction, also make collisons elastic. meaning particles jump back after collision